# ¿Cómo crear un buscador en php?

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Quisiera elaborar un buscador en el cual, al escribir una palabra, me aparecieran todos las coincidencias con esa palabra.
Formulario:

```
<form action="buscador.php" method="post">
    <input name="palabra" placeholder="Palabra">
    <input type="submit" name="buscador" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

Código PHP:

```
include('conexion.php');
if ($_POST['buscador']){
    // Tomamos el valor ingresado
    $buscar = $_POST['palabra'];

    // Si está vacío, lo informamos, sino realizamos la búsqueda
    if (empty($buscar)){
        echo "No se ha ingresado una cadena a buscar";
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE nombre like '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

        $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        // Imprimimos los resultados
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "Resultados para: <b>$buscar</b>";
        do {
            ?>
            <p><b><a href="productos.php?id=<?=$row['cve_imagenes'];?>"><?=$row['nombre'];?></a></b></p>
            <?php
        }while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
            echo "<p>Resultados: $total</p>";
        }else{
            // En caso de no encontrar resultados
            echo "No se encontraron resultados para: $buscar";
        }
    }
}
```

Y estos son los errores que me aparecen:

[image: errore]

Comment: Los parametros estan al revez aqui: `$result = mysqli_query($sql, $conexion);`

Comment: @alanfcm gracias, eso arregla el primer error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema podría estar en la conexión.

Si te está devolviendo un error en `mysqli_num_rows` porque le pasas null, es que algo viene mal de antes, concretamente de `mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);`, fíjate si con la línea que te he agregado usando [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) te dice el error de conexión.

```
include('conexion.php');
if (isset($_POST['buscador'])){
    // Tomamos el valor ingresado
    $buscar = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['palabra']);

    // Si está vacío, lo informamos, sino realizamos la búsqueda
    if (empty($buscar)){
        echo "No se ha ingresado una cadena a buscar";
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE nombre like '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        if ($result === false){
            echo mysqli_error($conexion);
        }else{
            $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            // Imprimimos los resultados
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "Resultados para: <b>$buscar</b>";
                do {
                ?>
                <p><b><a href="productos.php?id=<?=$row['cve_imagenes'];?>"><?=$row['nombre'];?></a></b></p>
                <?php
                }while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
                echo "<p>Resultados: $total</p>";
            }else{
                // En caso de no encontrar resultados
                echo "No se encontraron resultados para: $buscar";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

También te he agregado la función [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) porque mínimo tienes que escapar los strings introducidos por el usuario, lo ideal en realidad sería que usases sentencias preparadas (http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Gracias bro, me funciona excelente.

Comment: @Eduardo márcala como la respuesta correcta entonces, gracias

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, tienes los parametros al revez en `mysqli_query`.  Deberia ser asi:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

Luego en el query, me parece que estas usando las comillas incorrectas.  Intenta copiar y pegar esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE nombre like '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: gracias ya corregi el error de orden, tambien cambie las comillas pero aun asi me siguen apareciendo los errores de mysqli_num_rows y mysqli_fetch_array los ultimos de la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Esta un poco enredado tu algoritmo a la hora de imprimir los datos. Para ver si hay datos podrías comparar el valor de tu variable **$total** que sea mayor a 0 (indica que hay resultados) y ahí imprimes los datos, caso contrario imprimes mensaje **No se encontraron resultados...**

Anexo como quedaría al final:

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');
if ($_POST['buscador']) {
    // Tomamos el valor ingresado
    $buscar = $_POST['palabra'];

    // Si está vacío, lo informamos, sino realizamos la búsqueda
    if (empty($buscar)) {
        echo "No se ha ingresado una cadena a buscar";
    } else {        

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE nombre like '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id DESC";        
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);        
        $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        // Imprimimos los resultados

        //Modificacion de codigo....        
        if ($total > 0) {
            echo "Resultados para: <b>$buscar</b>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
       <p><b><a href="productos.php?id=<?= $row['cve_imagenes']; ?>"><?= $row['nombre']; ?></a></b></p>
        <?php
            }
            echo "<p>Resultados: $total</p>";
        } else {
            echo "No se encontraron resultados para: $buscar";
        }
    }
}
?>
```